# apply a database program (package, function or script )into oracle database from c#

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am trying to apply a function by using odp.net into my oracle database but I cannot, woul you mind help me please?
This program suppose to apply all the backend object for me into my database.( A file which is contain several ddl script[insert, create table or delete and alter table], apply function, procedure or package)

I am doing this activity for automate apply objects in our client side.

This software should work same as PLEdit software.

textbox1.text :

```
create or replace FUNCTION bfn_severity_temp (p_severity                CMMT_FIX_MASTER.N_severity%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2

    IS
   BEGIN
        IF p_severity = 1 THEN
            RETURN 'Mission Critical';
        ELSIF p_severity = 2 THEN
            RETURN 'High';
        ELSIF p_severity = 3 THEN
            RETURN 'Medium';
        ELSIF p_severity = 4 THEN
            RETURN 'High';
        END IF;
   END;
```

My c# code in as below:

```
try{
        OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);

            //OracleTransaction trans = oConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand();
            //oc.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            oc.CommandText = textBox1.Text;
            //oc.Transaction = trans;
            oc.Connection = oConn;
            int i  = 0;
            oConn.Open();
            i = oc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you seeing an exception?

Comment: what error do you get? I noticed you're discarding the exception on your try catch block...  Maybe you could try adding a `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);`

Comment: @Belogix well i is -1 and I am not receiving any exception, one more thing I cannot see my function in PLedit as valid or invalid object.

Comment: Does your connection string specify a valid user that has sufficient permission to perform the action you are trying?

Comment: yes I am using super user, as I said I can open connection and close connetion but problem is i result is -1 and I cannot see my function in list of applied function...

Comment: `i = -1` is normal. you're not doing an update, delete or insert statement... `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected by the query which in your case will be -1...

Comment: @bastos.sergio: so why I cannot see my new function in pledit?

Comment: Perhaps you're creating the object in another schema?

Comment: @bastos.sergio : :D imagine, no I am using same user,password and database details

Comment: @bastos.sergio, can you try it in your end? and share you point of view with me?

Comment: I don't have Oracle installed. I'm afraid I can't test your code... But I've had the same problems before, and it was always schema related... Here's the link to the [executenonquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) api, by the way...

Comment: I found that my object compiling but it is invalid! then when I compile it from PLEdit it was compiling succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just remember, looking at DDL you creating the object in the schema defined by connection. And if the super-user you connecting as is "System", that is the place to look for your object.
2. Your object may be invalid after creation but will be compiled on the first use (if object is compilable)
   Or, you can add the following `alter function <name> compile`